# Automatically enter search mode after presenting ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, abpeoplepickerview

I am using the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` class provided by Apple to let the user pick a contact.

In this list the user can  start searching by tapping into the searchBar. However I want that the user doesn't need to tap the searchBar and therefore I want to automatically enter into search mode after presenting the view controller.

For searchBar you can normally enter searchMode by calling `searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES`. This However does not seem to work using the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`.

That is what I tried:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
    [picker.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [picker.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is a navigationController, the searchBar you see is part of the `topViewController` or `visibleViewController` in that navigationController (which is actually of the class `ABMembersViewController` that is not exposed by the AddressBookUI API).

To activate the searchBar, you can do the following in the completion block:

```
[picker.visibleViewController.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
[picker.visibleViewController.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
```